# Proget service requires restart to show up in feed

Tags: proget

I have been having issues getting packages to update with their latest version until I restart the proget service.  I see no indexing errors and cannot figure out what is triggering that service to stop updating.

I have to get the service restarted about once a week now to keep everything updating properly.

Is there some additional logging or somewhere I can get more information on that server to determine what is causing the service to not update the feed??

Comment: What version are you running, what type of feed is it, and is symbol/source serving enabled? Any errors that aren't logged to ProGet's error log or indexing error log would be logged to the Windows event log.

Comment: Version 2.2.13 (Build 4).  And its a nuget feed with symbol/source server enabled.  I will check the event logs today.

Comment: Also, where are the packages stored, is it a local system path or a network drive/path?